# Why don't all open balls have a finite diameter?

Tags: real-analysis

This is probably really basic, but I can't seem to find where my thinking is going wrong.  My book says that for a subspace $S$, if there exists a supremum of $d(a,b)$ such that $d(a,b)\in S$, then $S$ has a finite diameter.  This makes sense, but for open balls, $d(a,b)<r$.  According to the least upper bound axiom, if a non-empty set is bounded above, it has a supremum.  Why doesn't it follow that for open (and closed) balls, $d(a,b)$ is bounded above and thus has a supremum and is always finite?

Comment: a subspace $S$ of *what*? What exactly is the supremum of? I cannot understand what you are asking, really. A ball has finite diameter, which is at most twice its radius (this follows immediately from the triangle inequality)

Comment: A subspace of a metric space.

Comment: There is no issue here. Open or closed balls do have finite diameter--but arbitrar subsets of metric spaces don't.

Comment: Then please add that information to the body of the question, so that it is complete.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that part, and thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 4):

If $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a metric space, $r>0$, and $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$, is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$, then for all $y,z\in B(x,r)$ we have

$$d(y,z)\le d(y,x)+d(x,z)<r+r=2r$$

by the triangle inequality. Thus,

$$\operatorname{diam}B(x,r)=\sup\{d(y,z):y,z\in B(x,r)\}\le 2r\;:$$

every open ball in every metric space has a diameter that is at most twice its radius. In particular, it has a finite diameter. An arbitrary open **set**, however, can be unbounded: the set $P$ of positive reals, for instance, is an open subset of $\Bbb R$ that does not have a finite diameter, because for any positive integer $n$, the points $1$ and $n+1$ are points of $P$ that are $n$ units apart.

Note, by the way, that an open ball can have a diameter smaller than twice its radius. In fact, it can have a diameter smaller than its radius. Let $X$ be any set, and for $x,y\in X$ let

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x=y\\1,&\text{if }x\ne y\;;\end{cases}$$

it’s easy to check that $d$ is a metric on $X$. However, it’s also easy to check that if $0<r\le 1$, then $B(x,r)=\{x\}$ has diameter $0$ for any $x\in X$, and that if $r>1$, then $B(x,r)=X$ has diameter $1$ for any $x\in X$.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear from your question, but it sounds as if this is what is going on:

Assume the subspace is the positive real line with the standard metric (within the entire real line with the same metric). Then each ball $B_{\epsilon}(x) := [x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon] \cap \mathbb{R^+}, x, \epsilon > 0$, has by definition finite radius. But when you look at the sequence of balls $B_n(n), n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, then the supremum over the radius of such balls goes to $\infty$.

As said, I'm not quite clear from your description if this answers your question, but it came to mind.

Comment: You and Brian each got at what was confusing me.  In the future I will try to phrase my questions in a clearer manner.

Comment: @user62117: That's part of learning math. :) The more you force yourself to be clear, the more you will be clear, and the easier it is to discuss with others successfully, and to get help when needed (MSE is essentially a public discussion). Good luck!